# Docker networks do not have consistent name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Depending on the host where I'm running Docker-compose, I get different network naming. For instance:

This is my docker-compose file:

`./my-project-folder/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:

  search:
    build: docker/server
    container_name: server
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

I have a project called `my-project-folder` and the network is called:

```
my-project-folder_default
```

But sometimes I get this network name:

```
myprojectfolder_default
```

Is there a way to have consistent network names?

Comment: Can you share your docker compose?

Comment: Added docker compose file @juanlumn

Answer (score 1):

[`docker-compose -p`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) or the [COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) will manually set that prefix, rather than letting Compose decide for itself based on the directory name.  This would still let you have multiple copies of the stack running on the same system if you needed to (forcing `container_name` and the network name would cause multiple deployments to conflict).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining an entry under `networks`?

```
version: '3'

services:

  search:
    build: docker/server
    container_name: server
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - your-network-name

networks:
  your-network-name: ...
```

There is some interesting information in the [Compose File Reference V3 Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-1)

According to the previous doc:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  search:
    build: docker/server
    container_name: server
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - your-network-name

networks:
  your-network-name:
   name: your-global-net
```

*Please note that you will need at least Docker Engine 17.06.0 for this to work and you need to use the latest version of docker-compose yml.*

To check that you can simply type:

```
docker version
```